# How to convert a unicode(ex: \u2713) code to a rune(ex: ✓) in golang?

Tags: go, character-encoding

**code:**

```
var checkMark = "\u2713"  // stand for rune "✓"
```

and how to convert unicode "\u2713" to the rune "✓" and print it ?
Is anyone can help me, Thanks a lot very much.

Answer (score 3):

As if you have a string like "\u2713\u2715".

See in playground https://play.golang.org/p/AxpnCzNEOfr

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    src := "\u2713\u2715"
    r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(src)
    fmt.Printf("the first rune of src is %v, code: %d",string(r), r)
}

// Output
// the first rune of src is ✓, code: 10003
```

More sample about `utf8.DecodeRuneInString` can find from answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274978/10737552

Comment: Thanks, but when I ran the code above, it display not normally.

Comment: the font you are using can't display that character.

Answer (score 1):

The [string literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) `"\u2713"` is a string containing the single rune `✓`.  No conversion is required.

Use the fmt package to print strings:  `fmt.Println("\u2713")`

To get the `✓` as a [rune](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals), use the rune literal `'\u2713'`

[Run it on the  playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2BcKW-T4JCI)